# Send file through TCP/IP C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, tcp, client-server

I am trying to create a server and client TCP/IP. I want to send file from client to server. I know that I must open the file in binary mode. I store data (read from file) in an unsigned char array.

I made a simple protocol: firstly, I added a character "\x02" to the first byte. Afterwards, in data, I added '|' after each character "\x02".

It works fine with a small text.

My problem: when I tested with a text file which contains 1024 characters "\x02", the progress is corrupted.

Here my client code:

```
  FILE *fr = fopen(fpath, "rb");
  char rec[32];

  int inc = 0;
  while(size>0){
     unsigned char buffer[1030];
     unsigned char data[2070] ;
     unsigned char header[1] = {'\x02'};   
     int bytesRead;

     if(size>=1024){
          bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1024, 1, fr);
         } else {
          bytesRead = fread(buffer, size, 1, fr);
         }

     memmove(sms,header,1);

     unsigned char *pch;
     int _countHead = 0;
     pch = (unsigned char*) memchr(buffer,"\x02",bytesRead);
     while(pch != NULL) {
          memmove(buffer + (pch-buffer+2),buffer + (pch-buffer+1),bytesRead);
          memmove(buffer + (pch-buffer+1), "|", 1);
          _countHead ++;
          pch = (unsigned char*) memchr(buffer + (pch - buffer + 1),"\x02",bytesRead);
     }

     memmove(sms,buffer,bytesRead + _countHead);

     send (m_socket,(char*) sms, bytesRead + _countHead,0);
     recv(m_socket,rec,2,0);
     size -= 1024;
     inc++;
  }

     if(NULL != fr){
         fclose(fr);
         fr = NULL;
     }
```

Thanks in advance :)

**Update**

I made a new code as your comments:

```
FILE *fa = fopen(fpath,"rb");

while(size>0){

    unsigned char buffer[1024];
    unsigned char buff[2048];
    unsigned char sms[2064];
    int _countHead = 0;
    int _countEnd = 0;

    if (size >= 1024)
    {
        bytesRead = fread(buffer,1,1024,fa);
    }
    else 
    {   
        bytesRead = fread(buffer,1,size,fa);
    }

    memcpy(buff,buffer,bytesRead);

    memset(sms,'#',2064);
    memset(numstr,'#',7);
    memcpy(sms,header,1);
    itoa(inc,numstr,10);        
    memcpy (sms+1,&numstr,7);

    unsigned char *pch;
    pch = (unsigned char*) memchr(buff,'\x02',bytesRead);
    while(pch != NULL)
    {
        int pos = pch - buff;
        memcpy (buff + pos + 2, buff + pos + 1, bytesRead);
        memcpy (buff + pos + 1, ext, 1);
        pch = (unsigned char*) memchr(buff + pos +1,'\x02',bytesRead - pos);
        _countHead ++;
    }

    pch = (unsigned char*) memchr(buff,'\x03',bytesRead);
    while(pch != NULL)
    {
        int pos = pch - buff;
        memcpy (buff + pos + 2, buff + pos + 1, bytesRead);
        memcpy (buff + pos + 1, ext, 1);
        pch = (unsigned char*) memchr(buff + pos + 1,'\x03',bytesRead);
        _countEnd ++;
    }

    memcpy (sms+8,buff,bytesRead + _countHead + _countEnd);
    memcpy (sms + (bytesRead + _countHead + _countEnd + 8),end,1);      
    memcpy (sms + (bytesRead + _countHead + _countEnd + 9),numstr,7);

    send(m_socket,(char*)sms,bytesRead + _countHead + _countEnd + 16 ,0);
    recv(m_socket,rec,2,0);

    size -= 1024;
}
```

Comment: Since you're sending binary data, you can't really use special separator bytes unless you escape them somehow in the binary stream. Instead I suggest you make a small fixed-sized header that you send first, containing the size of the file. This way the receiver can read the header and know the exact amount of bytes it needs to receive.

Comment: In addition to what @JoachimPileborg said, you should ensure to send the file length in network byte order, that it can safely be exchanged between different machine architectures.

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be in the network byte order as long as the byte order is clearly specified, so both the server and the client know which one to use.

Comment: Thanks you guys! As your comments, I make a small header which contains: the first byte is character '\x02' and the next seven bytes are the length of data. But my question is how the server can distinguish the header and data. Because data can contain characters as same as the header. Moreover, since data is transferred as stream, so it maybe receive less than length of data which is in header. Should I make a end of data which can be contain some special character?